# How can I group RadioMenuItem? (PyGtk)

Tags: python, radio-button, indicator

That's the question.

I'm making an indicator for Ubuntu, all works fine, but... When I try to set two "RadioMenuItem" they are totally independent. I can check both.

The items:

```
item_first = gtk.RadioMenuItem('First Radio')
item_first.connect('activate', first_radio)
menu.append(item_first)

item_second = gtk.RadioMenuItem('Second Radio')
item_second.connect('activate', second_radio)
menu.append(item_second)
```

Should I use a container or something like this? Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
self.menu = Gtk.Menu()
self.menu_items = list("First Radio","Second Radio")
group = []
for i in range(1,5):
    menu_item = Gtk.RadioMenuItem.new_with_label(group, str(i))
    group = menu_item.get_group()
    self.menu_items[i] = menu_item
    self.menu.append(menu_item)
    menu_item.connect("activate", self.on_menu_select, i)
    menu_item.show()

self.menu_items[2].set_active(True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, John Paul! Now that's the problem "self.menu_items = list("First Radio","Second Radio")
TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)"

Answer (score 1):

That's an old one, I know. However the solution is as following:

```
item_first = gtk.RadioMenuItem('First Radio')
item_first.connect('activate', first_radio)
menu.append(item_first)

item_second = gtk.RadioMenuItem('Second Radio', group=item_first) # <-- note group
item_second.connect('activate', second_radio)
menu.append(item_second)
```